# Opening Sharepoint Documents from Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office

Currently I am working on setting up Office 365, with focus on Sharepoint. It's still early days, so everything can still be changed, which is why I am asking this question before I hit a point-of-no-return.

When opening a document in (fx) Excel, I 'Add a Place' and choose Office 365 Sharepoint. However, this only links to my 'root' Team Site: domain.sharepoint.com, and I can only navigate to the subsites of that root site.

I can navigate to other sites by changing to url ->

```
domain.sharepoint.com/sites/projects/someproject
```

Is there a way to make this more user-friendly, so they can navigate easily to different sites from their Office Programs? Or do I really have to structure my Sharepoint to have domain.sharepoint.com as the main site collection and then make subsites all the way down for other sites? (This doesn't seem right).

Answer (score 0):

I have a idea,
You can add url to navigation in root Site? if positive, continue read this post, otherwise skip!

Only 4 step to configure this link:

1. In your root site:
   [image: first step - click edit link]
2. In edit mode, add link:
   [image: second step - adding link]
3. On adding link, fill in the data.
   [image: thirty step - link added]
4. Click OK and save:
   [image: quarter step - saving navigation]

Result:

[image]

And now, the your users can access with facility :)